# Detect which specific map pin was touched

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have a map view with a large number of pins, each having a unique annotation.  The map also shows the pulsing blue dot for the user location.  So far, I've only been able to determine if a pin was touched, but not the SPECIFIC pin that was touched.

How do I determine the specific pin in the map that was touched by the user?  I'm using Xcode v6.1.  Sample code (for one of many pins):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

//** Data for Location 1 **
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = 45.5262223;
    region.center.longitude = -122.63642379999999;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    [self.mapView setDelegate:self];

    DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
    ann.title = @"This is Location 1";
    ann.subtitle = @"1234 North Main Street";
    ann.coordinate = region.center;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:ann];

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    NSLog(@"This logs when any pin is touched, need to know which pin");

}
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks much for your accurate answer and detailed explanation. Sorry I can't up vote your answer, but my reputation isn't high enough.  But again, thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

In `didSelectAnnotationView`, the `view` parameter passed to the method contains a reference to the annotation it's associated with.

Before using the reference, you should check what type it is (eg. using `isKindOfClass`) and handle accordingly.  This is because the delegate method will be called when any annotation is tapped which includes the user location blue dot which is of type `MKUserLocation`.  It's also possible that your custom annotation objects have non-standard properties and attempting to access these on the wrong type of annotation will cause an exception.

Example:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    //Annotation that was selected is in the view parameter...
    id<MKAnnotation> annSelected = view.annotation;

    //See if this annotation is our custom type (DisplayMap)
    //and not something else like MKUserLocation...
    if ([annSelected isKindOfClass:[DisplayMap class]])
    {
        //Now we know annSelected is of type DisplayMap
        //so it's safe to cast it as type DisplayMap...
        DisplayMap *dm = (DisplayMap *)annSelected;

        NSLog(@"Pin touched: title=%@", dm.title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks from Mexico! =)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)aView
{
    NSInteger indexPathTag=aView.tag;
    [mapView deselectAnnotation:aView.annotation animated:YES];

}
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)aView
{
}
```

Simply use this code.Hope this will work for you. :)

Comment: Thanks!! I tried but i have a problem when increment the tag :(